# Parsing string in PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: plsql, format

```
DECLARE @steps LONG VARCHAR;
SET @steps='1200-abc,1300,1400-enhk1,1500'
```

I need to get `@steps` as `'1200,1300,1400,1500'`.

Please let me know how it is possible in stored procedure in PL/SQL

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate by occurences `regexp_substr`, or just select them like this

```
for item in (SELECT regexp_substr('1200-abc,1300,1400-enhk1,1500', '\w(\d+)\w', 1, LEVEL) val
      FROM dual
    CONNECT BY regexp_substr('1200-abc,1300,1400-enhk1,1500', '\w(\d+)\w', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
loop
      dbms_output.put_line(item.val);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make like this :

```
declare

  i varchar2(4000);
  v_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  only_numbers  varchar2(100) :='';
begin

  i := '1200-abc,1300,1400-enhk1,1500';

  v_array := apex_util.string_to_table(i, ',');

  for e in 1 .. v_array.count loop

      only_numbers:=only_numbers || regexp_substr(v_array(e),'[[:digit:]]*') ||',';


  end loop;

only_numbers := rtrim( only_numbers, ',' );
dbms_output.put_line(only_numbers);   -- output :  1200,1300,1400,1500

end;
```

Comment: Thanks all for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
create function del_non_numerics(str varchar2)
return varchar2
is
v_return_txt varchar2(3000);
begin
select regexp_replace(str,'[^0-9,]+','') into v_return_txt
from dual;

return v_return_txt;
end;
/
```

Invoking the above code as 
del_non_numerics('1200-abc,1300,1400-enhkl,1500') => 1200,1300,1400,1500